# bash: override echo to print a custom prefix in a script

Tags: bash, overloading, verbosity

I have some lengthy scripts calling each other and I want their output to be more descriptive. The idea is to customize the echo command for each script with something like below.

My question is, how to make it non recursive, using `echo`?

this is script1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#Original version:
#function echo(){ echo $(basename $0 .sh): $1; }
#Version after fixes
function echo(){ builtin echo -n "$(basename $0 .sh): ">&2; builtin echo $@ ; } 
echo Info
./script2.sh
```

this is script2.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#Original version:
#function echo(){ echo $(basename $0 .sh): $1; }
#Version after fixes
function echo(){ builtin echo -n "$(basename $0 .sh): ">&2; builtin echo $@ ; } 
echo Info
exit 0
```

so the output should be:

```
>./script1.sh
script1: Info
script2: Info
```

--- EDIT

Bonus:

```
>./script1.sh 2> /dev/null 
Info
Info
```

Comment: `unset -f echo` should be used afterwards

Comment: You could also put that function declaration into it's own file, and `source` it into the scripts that require it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use the `builtin` keyword:

```
function echo(){ builtin echo $(basename $0 .sh): $1; }
```

here the help page:

```
$ help builtin
builtin: builtin [shell-builtin [arg ...]]
    Execute shell builtins.

    Execute SHELL-BUILTIN with arguments ARGs without performing command
    lookup.  This is useful when you wish to reimplement a shell builtin
    as a shell function, but need to execute the builtin within the function.

    Exit Status:
    Returns the exit status of SHELL-BUILTIN, or false if SHELL-BUILTIN is
    not a shell builtin..
```

Comment: +1; but instead of `$1`, it would be better to write `"$@"`. (And note that this function disables all of `echo`'s special features, like `-E` and `-n`.)

Comment: @lesmana: Nice, like it was designed to solve this problem :D Thank you!

Comment: @ruakh Options like  `-E` and `-n` are not necessarily disabled. They are [specified for the built in function](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) and they work for me. For example: `builtin echo -e "\e[1;31m red"`... but I think the `-e` option will be disabled if running in POSIX mode or bash compiled with `--enable-xpg-echo-default`; however, in that case the `-e` option is only disabled because it's already turned on.

Comment: @u8it: I think you must have misunderstood my comment. Your example of `builtin echo -e "\e[1;31m red"` isn't relevant, because the function in this answer would instead run `builtin echo name_of_script -e "\e[1;31m red"`.

Comment: Gotcha, in reference to the wrapper function itself. Still, the wrapper doesn't really disable those features. They could be enabled other ways like POSIX mode or `--enable-xpg-echo-default`, but this wrapper would not handle them as arguments... and it's still relevant to clarify that the builtin function supports those flags.

Answer (score 2):

`builtin` only works for shell internal commands like `echo`. I know the original question is specifically related to `echo`, but as this was a popular Google hit for "bash override function", I thought I'd add my solution for other commands. I'm writing a wrapper to change terminal name when I run `ssh`, so I defined a function called `ssh` and need to call the actual binary from within. It may not be the best way, but it works to do:

```
function ssh {
    $(which ssh) $@
}
```

Comment: The standard way to do that would be `command ssh "$@"` (where `command` bypasses any shell function in favor of *either* a shell builtin *or* an external program).

Answer (score 0):

I came up with I/O redirection as a solution. The [Bash Redirections Using Exec](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-redirections-using-exec) article inspired me. It has the following implications:

- Redirect the script's standard or error output no matter which command prints to it, e.g. echo, printf, etc.
- No repetitive work for subshells or sourced scripts.
- Redirection extends to any executable that is being called by this script, a subscript or sourced script thereof.
- Filters can be composed by creating several pipes where one pipe redirects its output into the input of the next, and so on.

In my `bash` shell scripts I use:

```
alias start_log_ctx="start_filter_by_pipe_regex 2 s/.*/${0##*/}\(pid=$$\): \0/"
function start_filter_by_pipe_regex {
  declare -r a="$(mktemp -u)" #1
  mknod "$a" p                #2
  sed <"$a" ">&$1" "$2" &     #3
  exec "$1">"$a"              #4
}

alias stop_log_ctx_by_job="stop_filter_by_pipe_job 2"
def stop_filter_by_pipe_job {
  exec "$1">&- #1
  wait "$2" #2
}
```

In essence the `start_log_ctx` alias uses `sed` to line-wise (`.*`) filter the script's I/O that goes to the error output (`2`) and prepends the script's base name (`${0##*/}`) and process id (`pid=$$`) to each line. The `start_filter_by_pipe_regex` function works as follows:

1. Store the absolute path of but do not create (`-U`) a temporary file.
2. Create a pipe under the absolute path of [1.].
3. Start `sed` as a filter in the background (`&`). Let it read (`<`) from the pipe of [2.] and redirect its standard output (`>`) to the file descriptor given as the 1. parameter. Pass the filter given as 2. parameter to `sed`.
4. Redirect (`>`) the file descriptor given as the 1. parameter to the pipe of [2.].

The `stop_log_ctx` alias closes the error output's file descriptor (`2`) and waits for the previously started `sed` to stop. It implicitly does so upon closing the file descriptor. The `stop_filter_by_pipe_job` function does the following:

1. Close the file descriptor given as the 1. parameter thereby stopping `sed`.
2. Wait for the background `sed` identified by the bash job given as the 2. parameter to stop.

At the beginning of my main function I usually do a `declare -r a="$(start_log_ctx)"` and finish with a `stop_log_ctx_by_job "$a"`.

Comment: One could also use `mkfifo "$a"` instead of `mknod "$a" p`.